# JNLP doesn't start correctly in browser (deployed with dtjava.js)

Tags: java, javafx, jnlp

I just start with JNLP technology and some JavaFX code. I have try to run my first application inside browser deploying with dtjava.js (Deployment Toolkit JavaScript file). I deploy this with dtjava.launch(...). My problem is every time I open HTTP in the browser it redirects me to Oracle page to download actual Java 7 up 25. I reinstalled my java which was already in fact 7 up 25. And again the redirection to Oracle site .... This could be done in endless loop.....

My system : Windows XP SP3 
browsers: chrome, firefox... 
Java version : 7 up 25

This behavior is not observed on Windows 7.

Comment: *"(you can google that)"*  I can, but won't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the Java version 7up25 plugins in the browsers. I downgraded to Java to 7up21 and jnlp starts correctly. If you can get it from Oracle site because they force you to have a login account, search for installer via google.

Comment: Or you could take the more sensible approach of informing Oracle in a bug report..